# How To Change MsoButtonicon To msobuttoncaption

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am making add in toolbar and want to display button as text. Any suggestions?

```
With oButton2
    .DescriptionText = "This is my first button"
    .Caption = "Bullets"
    .OnAction = "Button2"
    .Style = msoButtonIcon
    .FaceId = 55 'chooses icon #55 from the available Office icons
End With
```

Comment: See [this Q+A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2901691/1490783) for tips on how to learn VBA.

Comment: With oButton2

         .DescriptionText = "This is my first button"

         .Caption = "Bullets"

         .OnAction = "Button2"

         .Style = msoButtonIcon
           .FaceId = 55
           chooses icon #55 from the available Office icons
    End With

Comment: Please update your question to add code, much easier to read there. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the .Style bit to this

```
.Style = msoButtonCaption
```